# ¿No puedo realizar esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero sumar los valores que hay en `VLR_TOTAL` donde`NOMBRE` sea igual `Expansion` y `NOMBRE` sea igual a`Mantenimiento.`

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT SUM(VLR_TOTAL) FROM bodega_moviles WHERE NOMBRE = Expansion AND 
    NOMBRE = Mantenimiento
```

pero me arroja como resultado

```
SUM(VLR_TOTAL)
 NULL
```

Comment: Tienes algún dato en la BD que cumplas 2 condiciones?

Comment: Y Expansion y Mantenimiento que son, strings o columnas?

Comment: Expansion y mantenimiento son string del campo `NOMBRE` y quiero sumar los valores(registros) del campo `VLR_TOTAL`

Comment: Yo realizo esta consulta: `SELECT SUM(VLR_TOTAL) FROM `bodega_moviles` `WHERE NOMBRE = `'Mantenimiento Cali'` y me arroja un resultado y quiero sumar el resultado de la anterior consulta con `SELECT SUM(VLR_TOTAL) FROM `bodega_moviles` WHERE NOMBRE = 'Expansion'`, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, cambia tu operador `AND` por un `OR`:

```
SELECT SUM(VLR_TOTAL) 
FROM bodega_moviles 
WHERE NOMBRE = 'Expansion' OR
NOMBRE = 'Mantenimiento'
```

Al decir `NOMBRE = [algún valor] AND NOMBRE = [algún otro valor]` estás diciendole a la consulta que el campo `NOMBRE` debería ser igual a 2 valores diferentes, cosa que no puede ser.

También puedes hacer uso del operador `IN` de la siguiente forma para evitar redundancia:

```
SELECT SUM(VLR_TOTAL) 
FROM bodega_moviles 
WHERE NOMBRE IN ('Expansion', 'Mantenimiento')
```

Comment: A menos que Expansion y Mantenimiento sean iguales... pero si, seria raro xD Para eso poner el igual entre ellos

Comment: Es correcta la respuesta, pero por costumbres de buena programación, en vez de usar "NOMBRE = Expansion OR
NOMBRE = Mantenimiento", cambialo por NOMBRE IN ('Expansion ', 'Expansion '). Usando así el IN en vez de repetir la condición.Saludos

Comment: @Rostan justo estaba editando mi respuesta para agregar dicha solución!

Comment: Pero en este caso estás comparando la columna `NOMBRE` con las columnas `Expansion` y `Mantenimiento`, cuando lo más probable es que quiera compararlo con strings

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorius lo solucione en base a tu respuesta

Comment: ¿Por qué el negativo?

Comment: Pues porque la respuesta estaba mala hasta que @Rostan la editó

Comment: Un heroe sin capa... haha, bueno despues de todo @AnderssonViverosMartinez pudo resolver su problema... es lo importante.